# CSS "word-spacing" property for input elements not working in Opera

Tags: css, forms, opera

CSS `word-spacing` property for `input` elements not working in Opera

Am I doing something wrong? Is this valid or invalid?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Input word spacing test</title>
        <style>
            input
            {
                word-spacing: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <article>
            <input type="text" value="This is a test."/>
        </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding `type="text/css"` to that `<style>` tag.  Probably won't fix it, but it's a good practice, anyway.

Comment: @Zenexer, yeah, still not working.

Comment: Is it working properly in other browsers? According to http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/word-spacing Opera is a little buggy with the word spacing property.

Comment: @chipcullen, yes. It works in other browsers. That's why I specifically mentioned Opera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug of Opera which is our bug reporting system with the id DSK-357174.

Comment: I was the one who submitted it. Thanks for confirming that it is a bug.